# Handling hardware with polyspace

Tags: c, code-analysis

I am working with Mathworks Polyspace for my CODE analysis. I have a hardware register where I write a KEY+MODE and read the register to check the value in the register is equal to MODE.

The problem is, Polyspace considers this as 'always fail' as I am writing and reading different values in consecutive steps.

Is there any option in Polyspace to handle this issue.?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking, could you post a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since KEY+MODE is different from MODE, Polyspace will logically consider the test `your_hardware_register == MODE` as failed (fortunatly).

It seems that KEY and MODE are bit flags for your register.
So I see two options:

1. Use the bitwise AND operator to test the register : `if (your_hardware_register & MODE)`
2. make the register volatile (by adding the qualifier volatile to the declaration of your register) so Polyspace will consider that it can take any value (including MODE).

Comment: Declaring the Register as 'volatile' worked. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The 1st approach is really nice as well, as it is effectively adding a validation in your code that also provides additional context on what is expected.  Of course, there has to be a good one to add, as you can't just go around your code adding conditionals without requirements to support the added code.